# Targetting players with a specific score doesn't seem to work

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How can I target a player with a specific score? For example: Set the score of `Score` to 100 for every player with 1 Point in the scoreboard objective `ScoreB`. I tried

```
/scoreboard players add @a[score_Score_min=1] Score 1
```

and it actually worked. But then i set the score for a "player" named "Test" to 1 and it didn't get points. What did I do wrong?

Comment: If "Test" is a fake player, he can not be targeted by target selectors, since those only resolve entities.

Comment: So what i used was actually right?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like "Test" is not a real player.

The problem in this case is that target selectors like `@a[...]` can only *resolve / find* entities that exist somewhere in the world and are loaded.

This means that while you can change the scores of fake or offline players (scoreboard scores are stored in `scoreboard.dat` rather than `playerdata`) by specifying their name directly, i.e.

```
/scoreboard players set Rayset Score 29
```

You can not use target selectors unless there is an entity to resolve.

If an entity exists, your command is correct. `@a[score_Score_min=1]` resolves all player entities with a `Score` score of at least 1.